# No .Net Framework 4 Features listed in Server Features in Wk8 R2 Standard Server, despite .Net 4 being installed

Tags: .net, windows-server-2008-r2

I need HTTP Activation installed on the server (Windows 2008 R2 Standard). .Net 4 is verified as installed, yet there is no listing under Features for .Net Framework 4.0... But .Net 3.5.1 is listed.

What needs to be done to get .Net 4.0 features installed?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF with 3.5 and 4.0 together](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675428/wcf-with-3-5-and-4-0-together)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server 2008 R2 was released on July 22, 2009.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008_R2

At that time, .NET 4 was not yet released (which was finally released on April 12, 2010),

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history

Thus, you can only see .NET 3.5 related features in Server Manager.

All .NET 4 bits need to be manually installed and configured aside  (such as running aspnet_regiis and ServiceModelReg).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Server 2008 if you enabled this feature for .NET 3.5 and then install .NET 4.0 this will be installed and enabled for .NET 4.0. If this was not enabled before .NET 4.0 install then this is a little bit more difficult. Probably the easiest way is to enable this feature for 3.5 and reinstall .NET 4.0...
See following related question "[WCF .NET 4.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784908/wcf-net-4-5-on-windows-server-2008-r2)" on StackOverflow.